# Should decimal number values assigned to CSS properties be rounded?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, numbers, rounding

Currently I am assigning values with decimals which come from a *CSS pre-processor* or from calculations from *JavaScript*. On one hand the value is more precise without modifying it and there is one less operation to be done, but on the other hand after the first digit the following are unnoticeable and I am not sure if these affect the browser performance in some way.

---

`div { width: 33.333333333333%; }`

vs

`div { width: 33.33%; }`

---

`$('div').width(100 / 3); // 33.3333...`

vs

`$('div').width(Math.round(100 / 3 * 100) / 100); // 33.33`

---

**Does it affect the browser performance to have several decimal values in the CSS?**

---

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/3evpazsp/) is a very basic example.

Comment: While no CSS definition prescribes the way `<number>` values are implemented, why would any rendering engine use anything but floating point numbers? And in this case, there is definitely no performance effect.

Comment: This is a reasonable question. Numbers are parsed from strings, so longer numbers will take longer to parse. Parsing any one number is trivial, but this "long" number may be used in lots of css variables and calculations, so in a 60fps animation, it's _possible_ this could add up. I don't have a real answer for you just now. (Sorry!)